# What do we want to measure when training agents?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

When training RL agents, there are a lot of heuristics that come into play, (I believe due to stochasticity, specificity of problems and so on).

However, I have seen in several papers measures that people (almost) always measure when training RL agents to see if it is actually learning. I will list those and I would like to know more important measures to look at when training or some rules of thumb/sanity checks that experienced people have encountered.

- Average Reward (*over x number of episodes*)
- Loss function (usually in Deep RL)
- # of actions (in grid world examples)
- Plots of the policy (violin plots)

Somebody have more to add?